# ColdFusion 9 : View SOAP XML before processing it

Tags: soap, coldfusion

I am trying to control access to web service methods by stopping the request in application.cfm/cfc before it gets processed by the CFC web service code.  Basically, I want to see what method is being requested and immediately abort the request if necessary.

For RESTful connections, I can look at the URL and FORM scopes to determine which method is being called.  But for SOAP requests, the method being requested is embedded in the XML SOAP message and I can't seem to access it without using getHttpRequestData(), which breaks the SOAP request!

I've tried using getPageContext().getRequest()... but can't find anyway to access the SOAP message.

Is there some other way to view the XML SOAP message or determine which web service method is being called?

Comment: 40 views, no answers, no comments.  What you are attempting might not be possible.

Comment: In my quick test I found the method name in the cgi variable CONTENT_TYPE. 

My example of what came through via my webservice call is below. The method being called was getQuery.

application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="urn:getQuery"

Comment: @AlanBullpitt Thanks, I went through the CGI vars carefully and CONTENT_TYPE is empty when I dump it during the request.  I may have a solution in the works but it's kind of ugly.  I will post if my tests work..

Answer (score 0):

Try to intercept the request in the `onRequestStart()` or `onCFCRequest()` event handler within Application.cfc. The use case you describe sounds as if `onCFCRequest()` is your handler.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe821657cd7d6f83f6daaa733122cf6931bb-8000.html

If that does not solve your issue, check out the docs for the `getSOAPRequestHeader()` function. That may put you in the right direction.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6ca1.html